# Unselect Attribute "Is Default" - Color

Tags: magento2, attributes, color-swatches, default-values

Magento 2.2.6

The attribute 'color' had, for as long as I can remember, no "Is Default" value selected.

A few days ago, I add a new color to the color value. Upon saving, there is now a color value selected as "Is Default".

I try to un-check "Is Default", but there's no effect. Then I try to change the "Is Default" to the top color value and save. But the "Is Default" is still check for the value 'Yellow', which is at the bottom of the sort.

I had to add a new size value and the same thing happened, the last value for 'size' now shows "Is Default". Same behavior if I try to change the 'Is Default', will revert back to the last sorted value. Even if I change the sort, the 'Is Default' will always be the last value of the attribute.

Does anyone have any idea what may be causing this issue? I may be after the 2.2.6 upgrade, but I hadn't added a color or size in some time, so I'm not sure.

And my system.log shows nothing but a LOT of cron jobs.

EDIT: When no 'Size' is selected, the last value in the sorted order for size will show. [image: Last Size from Sorted Value]

What ends up making this so annoying is the sizes are going to the product feed and I can't seem to get rid of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A work around is all I can seem to achieve. Add a new color. Save the attribute. Then delete the last color. Now the default color is again blank.

Not a good solution, but it does work.